# recyclerview in FirebaseRecyclerviewAdapter turn all longth but write just one

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have a regular RecyclerView in FRA I set up in onbindviewholder class. İt turns longth as you see in app there is a space for all items normally I should see there reply text but just one can see.

```
dbreply.child(post_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                     for (DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                         for (DataSnapshot snapshot1:ds.getChildren()) {
                             reply data = snapshot1.getValue(reply.class);
                             list.add(data);
                      
                             holder.rcv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                             myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), list);
                             holder.rcv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                             myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                     }

                             @Override
                             public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that behavior because you are creating a new instance of MyAdapter at each iteration of the inner loop. What you should is to get all those 4 lines of code out of the loop, as you can see below:

```
for (DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot1:ds.getChildren()) {
        reply data = snapshot1.getValue(reply.class);
        list.add(data);
    }
    holder.rcv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), list);
    holder.rcv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```